# Selecting row in kendo grid when virtualization is enabled

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendoUI grid widget to display dataset. Because size of dataset is quite large (200-400k) I'm using virtualization feature to improve performance and usability. When setting grid up I have faced with the following problem: because virtualization is enabled, grid DOM objects (i mean table rows here) are refreshed every time when page is changed. That implementation of grid results in the following behavior: I can select row but after scrolling down to next page and scrolling back selection disappears. Here is example where this problem can be reproduced: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/OkOg

Maybe someone has similar problem and can offer some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the selection in the grid's `dataBound` event, e.g. like this (note that this only works for single row selection, so you might need to adapt for other modes):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    change: function () {
        this._lastSelectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
    },
    dataBound: function () {
        var row;
        if (this._lastSelectedItem) {
            row = $(this.tbody).find("tr[data-uid='" + this._lastSelectedItem.uid + "']")
            if ($(row).length > 0) {
                // or this.select(row); if you don't mind the 
                // change event getting triggered again
                $(row).addClass("k-state-selected");     
            }
        }
    },
    height: 430,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    selectable: true,
    columns: columns
});
```